# php: How can I rerun a script from the command line?

Tags: php

I have a script that parses a csv file.  When the script completes it returns to the command prompt.

What I want to do is when the script finishes it asks the user if they want to rerun it, the user enters "yes" or "no", yes reruns it and no exists the script.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: `$rerun_flag = true; if ($rerun_flag) { $rerun_flag = false; //asks to restart } else { //terminates }`

Comment: that all makes sense, its the asking to restart and capturing the user input that I don't know how to do

Comment: Ok then, if it's command line [read this](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php)

Comment: Nice one thank you, that's what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I arrived at:

```
$rerun_flag=true;
while($rerun_flag == true){
    //do stuff

    echo "\n\nDo you wish to rerun?  Enter 'yes' or 'no' without quotes: \n\n";
    $rerun_flag=false;
    $line = trim(fgets(STDIN)); // reads one line from STDIN
    if($line == 'yes'){
        $rerun_flag=true;
    } else {
        $rerun_flag=false;
        exit;
    }
}
```